# How to show different items in navbar and when clicked on collapsed button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angularJS along with bootstrap 3.2. I use navbar with some items.
The default behavior with bootstrap is when collapsed occurs then the same those items from navbar can be shown in dropdown panel if click on the newly appeared button.

How can I show different items in dropdown panel when in collapsed mode.
I would like to use as much built-in functionality as possible in both angularJS and bootstrap, and minimize hacks and workaround.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button id="collapse-button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"  aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="logo left navbar-brand">
            <a href="#!/main">
                <img src="logo.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" ng-cloak>
        <div class="navbar-avatar clearfix flLeft">
            <img src="avatar.png" title="" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

For example I want this "avatar.png" to be show differently (for examle in circle or in rectangle) if it is on the navbar or shown by clicking on the collapsed button.

Comment: A fiddle would be nice

Comment: I do not think fiddle is needed is this case, because this is default bootstrap's navbar behavior, but check out this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the css media query:

```
.buttons-i-only-show-when-collapsed {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .buttons-i-only-show-when-collapsed {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.hide-only-if-collapsed {
    display: block;
}

.show-only-if-collapsed {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .show-only-if-collapsed {
        display: block;
    }    
    .hide-only-if-collapsed {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

With minor modifications accepted answer works

Answer (score 1):

just add .hidden-xs at the div you want to hide

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="row hidden-xs">
```

and visible-xs the div you want to show

```
<div class="row visible-xs">
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest and cleanest solution - well done!